# Pandoc 4th Level Markdown Headers

Tags: markdown, org-mode, pandoc, github-flavored-markdown

I am working on converting a bunch of orgmode files into markdown. I have been unable to find how to prevent pandoc from converting headings greater than level 3 into numbered lists. For example:

```
* Heading 1

Here is some content

** Heading 2

Here is some content

*** Heading 3

Here is some content

**** Heading 4

Here is some content

***** Heading 5

Here is some content

**** Another Heading 4

Here is some content

***** Another Heading 5

Here is some content
```

Converting with this command: `pandoc -f org -t gfm --atx-headers myfile.org`

Results in this output:

```
# Heading 1

Here is some content

## Heading 2

Here is some content

### Heading 3

Here is some content

1.  Heading 4
    
    Here is some content
    
    1.  Heading 5
        
        Here is some content

2.  Another Heading 4
    
    Here is some content
    
    1.  Another Heading 5
        
        Here is some content
```

How can I have Heading 4 and Heading 5 be actual headings instead of numbered lists?

Thanks

Comment: Why not write a `awk` or `sed` command to make the change?

Comment: @RedCricket, can you elaborate on your suggestion? After performing this conversion, it's hard (or impossible) to distinguish between level 4 headings and lists that are intended to be numbered lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Org mode uses the [`H` export setting](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html) to control this behavior:

> Set the number of headline levels for export (`org-export-headline-levels`).
> Below that level, headlines are treated differently. In most back-ends, they
> become list items.

Pandoc respects this setting. The default value for this, both in Emacs Org-mode and pandoc, is 3.

So the solution for your issue is to set this to a higher value. Either add this to the top of your org file:

```
#+OPTIONS: H:9
```

Or, if you are on Mac or Linux, use your shell's process substitution feature to prefix your input with this line:

```
pandoc -f org -t gfm --atx-headers <(printf "#+OPTIONS: H:9") myfile.org
```